# Send email from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows command line emailer](https://superuser.com/questions/63081/windows-command-line-emailer)

I am looking for a program that can send an email from the command line, or more specifically from a script.  Searching through superuser I've found a lot of Linux solutions but I'd like something which can run in Windows (XP or 2003).  I have come across a program called "blat."  Has anyone had any positive results with this program? Negative?  Or could you offer other suggestions?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/63081/windows-command-line-emailer

Comment: Lots of options here.  Much appreciated DHayes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used blat, but I have used [bmail](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm). It's very simple, small (17kb) and can easily be used in batch scripts.

```
C:\>bmail /?

    Command Line SMTP Emailer V1.07
    Copyright(C) 2002-2004 Craig.Peacock@beyondlogic.org
    Usage: bmail [options]
            -s    SMTP Server Name
            -p    SMTP Port Number (optional, defaults to 25)
            -t    To: Address
            -f    From: Address
            -b    Text Body of Message (optional)
            -h    Generate Headers
            -a    Subject (optional)
            -m    Filename (optional) Use file as Body of Message
            -c    Prefix above file with CR/LF to separate body from header
            -d    Debug (Show all mail server communications)
```

bmail is freeware.

Comment: you're very welcome! :)

Comment: Just implemented this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

powershell 2.0 has a send-mail cmdlet built in.
Example:

```
Send-MailMessage –From me@myDomain.com –To you@Yourdomain.com –Subject   
"Test Email" –Body "Testing the cmdlet" –SmtpServer smtp.mydomain.com
```

Comment: I didn't realize that.  I'll definitely have to look at that.  Thank you James

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), or have been considering it anyway, you can use the 'email' package to send e-mail from the Cygwin command-line (or bash script therein).

This three-part Intro-to-Cygwin tutorial includes a quick-start that happens to demonstrate sending email from the Cygwin command-line.  [Pt1](http://lifehacker.com/software/cygwin/geek-to-live--introduction-to-cygwin-part-i-179514.php) [Pt2](http://lifehacker.com/software/cygwin/geek-to-live%E2%80%94introduction-to-cygwin-part-ii--more-useful-commands-180690.php) [Pt3](http://lifehacker.com/software/command-line/geek-to-live%E2%80%94introduction-to-cygwin-part-iii--scripts-packages-and-more-181282.php)

And, if it happens to pique your interest, I found that tutorial via [this one](http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server) on setting up an SSH server at home via Cygwin.

Comment: This certainly has piqued my interest.  It may meet another of my needs for a syslog server in Windows.  What a bonus.  Thanks indeed JMD.